# Positioning of menu items in toolbar on two pane layout

Tags: android, toolbar, menu-items

I am developing the tablet version of an app and have a 2 pane layout (master-detail) with 2 fragments, where the left fragment contains one menu item and the right fragment contains several menu items. As a default, all menu items of both fragments are displayed on the right end of the toolbar.

How can i position the menu-item of the left fragment directly above the right upper corner of this fragment (See the gmail app on tablets in landscape mode as an example -> [gmail tablet](https://lh5.ggpht.com/WK1g2s6NMv0pWJPJPfGBf2tzDgxI0IdSj4YFB2YrZhOI3f3-5sJIYjLLwKF7AEJmfgc=h900))?

Comment: Did you found out answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on relative values of **orderInCategory** under each menu item, even for items in different menu files upon rendered in two pane mode.

This will show lower

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_sort_popular"
    android:title="@string/sort_popularity"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

And this will show higher up

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_sort_rating"
    android:title="@string/sort_rating"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really find anything on this, apart from [this tutorial](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/supporting-phones-and-tablets-v1) (Scroll down half way to section `Split Toolbar for Tablets`).

It gets the job done, however i'm not sure if its the correct way of doing it.